# max vertical distance between two functions

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x^2$. $x \in [0,1]$. What is the max vertical distance between $f$ and $g$.

someone says when $d' = 0$ is the maximum, so $d = x - x^2$, $d' = 1 - 2x = 0$, then $x = 1/2$. Therefore max $d = 1/2-1/4 = 1/4$

i dont know why $d' = 0$ is the maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d'$ is the rate of change of $d$. If $d'=0$ then $d$ is no longer changing - so you have reached a maximum (or minimum value).

Comment: so how do u know ii's the maximum or minimum?

Comment: One way is to try values a little either side to see what they are. So you could try working out $d$ when $x=0.4$ and when $x=0.6$. You get $0.4-0.4^2=0.4-0.16=0.24$ and $0.6-0.6^2=0.6-0.36=0.24$. Compare these to when $x=0.5$ - you get $0.5-0.5^2=0.5-0.25=0.25$ - so this is a maximum.

Comment: You can also use the second derivative test, it's the easier option here.  Here, that's just $-2$, which is obviously negative, so any stationary point is a maximum.

Comment: @Deepak i agree with u.

Comment: @Deepak I agree, too, but would be cautious. Remember that you can have situations where the second derivative is zero. In those cases the stationary point can be a maximum, a minimum or a point of inflection. Looking a the values either side will therefore be useful.

Comment: @tomi Yes but that's why I highlighted that it works well in this case. Easy to find and obviously negative. I like your method as a more general one (except in rapidly oscillating functions).  :)

Comment: @Deepak I agree. In general, I usually recommend to my students checking the gradient either side rather than the function itself. But I wonder why...